# Get subset of values in dictionary by value properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, dictionary

**Original question:**

I have a Dictionary. How can I get only subset-collection of values where

e.g: `object.Age == 30` or `object.gender == "male"` etc.

**Question reworded to be more general and helpful to other users:**

In a dictionary where the key is a simple type such as string or int but my values are objects, how do I search the values by their properties and return a subset of values?

i.e in general lets say I have

```
Dictionary<string, myObject> dict = new Dictionary<string, myObject>();
```

And I want to search on myObject.someInt == X and myObject.someString = 'XYZ', how would I do this?

Comment: You want to get subset as what?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14538510/922198

Comment: My question has been answered :) thanks for your rapidly answers!

Comment: @user615993: Remember to accept an answer(order by quality, time).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Dictionary.Values`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ekcfxy3x.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx):

```
var age30OrMale = dict.Values.Where(o => Age == 30 || o.gender == "male");
foreach(var o in age30OrMale)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you want a new collection you can use `ToList` or `ToArray`

```
var list = age30OrMale.ToList();
```

Note that this is not a subset of the dictionary itself, hence it's no an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`. But it is what you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use lambda:

```
var newDictionary = myDictionary.Values.Where(d => d.Age == 30);
```

EDIT:

Based on your revised question:

```
var newDictionary = myDictionary.Values.Where(d => d.Age == 30 || d.Gender == "male");
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "etc.", but you can keep building that up using `||` and / or `&&`

EDIT:

As correctly pointed out by @Guffa, the resulting value is NOT a dictionary:

```
var newSubset = myDictionary.Values.Where(d => d.Age == 30 || d.Gender == "male");
```

Comment: Note: The `newDictionary` varible is not a dictionary.

Comment: No - it will return IEnumerable - he asked for a "subset collection" - not a dictionary

Comment: Yes, but you specifically named the variable as if it was a dictionary.

Comment: Good point - not sure why I didn't spot that earlier.  Oh well, that's what code reviews are for!

Answer (score 2):

```
var newDictionary = myDictionary.Values.Where(d => d.Age == 30 || d.gender == "male").ToDictionary();
```

Comment: There is no parameterless overload of the `ToDictionary` method.

Answer (score 1):

You just loop through the values and get those items:

```
List<MyObject> result = myDictionary.Values.Where(o => Age == 30).ToList();
```

Comment: Identifier expected, but found "=".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Sorry, missed the variable name.